# I am seeing oscillation in this SK bandpass filter circuit even without any input

Tags: operational-amplifier, band-pass

[image: SKBPF]

There is a constant 8-9 kHz oscillation without any input. Otherwise the output is as expected. The open op-amps were terminated as follows negative feedback connection made and non inverting input connected to 2.5 V as the op-amps are biased between 0-5 V.
This is a Sallen Key topology with non unity feedback.

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: When a circuit is able to oscillate - it will oscillate, independent on the existence of an input signal. Please, redraw your circuit diagram - it is very hard to read it.

Comment: @Antonio51 I will check that in the circuit. Thank you.

Comment: @LvW Please see if it is readable now. Thank you

Comment: @Antonio51 I checked in the main circuit. C7 is indeed connected to 2.5V. Only the drawing here was wrong.

Comment: Is this a simulation problem or a PCB test problem? What op-amp and what power supply circuits do you have?

Comment: The 8k and 5k resistors are swapped causing the gain to be too high. If built on a breadboard the stray capacitance all over the place adds to the very high gain causing oscillation.

Comment: @Andyaka it is a PCB test problem. Power supply from DC source and op amp used is LM358

Comment: @Audioguru Ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems working very well.

Please, use labels where possible for supplies, ground ... No crossing wires ...

If realized at lab, did you use decoupling capacitors very nearest to the supply pins ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But despite good simulation result I faced this issue in the PCB circuit.

Comment: Then, show your PCB ... add it in the question.

Comment: if I add the layout of the PCB will it be ok for you? I have used LM358 op amp ic